# How do I detect if jQuery is in a document navigated to in the WinForm WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, jquery, winforms, dom, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows Forms application in C#/Visual Studio 2008 with an IE WebBrowser control.  In the DocumentCompleted event, I want to search the WebBrowser.Document or WebBrowser.DomDocument to see if jQuery is already present in the page.

What's a good way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try:

```
bool hasjQuery = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("jQuery") != null;
```

Comment: Thanks!, I'll mark you as the answer as soon as I can test it in a few cases.